# Installable created via CMake on Windows outputting error even when none when debugging it?

Tags: c++, windows, installation, cmake, clion

## Problem

### Synopsis

I am currently going through the CMake tutorial to deepen my understanding of the build system. So far, I have had no issues, but I am currently on [Step5 - Exercise 1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Installing%20and%20Testing.html#exercise-1-install-rules) learning about how to use CMake to make an installable executable using the `install()` command. While I am successfully running `cmake --install`. When I attempt to run the **Tutorial.exe** file either from my program x86 directory *or* my Desktop, I get a runtime issue as seen below...

```
←[31;1mNativeCommandExitException: ←[31;1mProgram "Tutorial.exe" ended with non-zero exit code: -1073741819.←[0m
```

Any insight on how to fix this or what is going on would be appreciated. From my limited understanding it appears the code for `MathFunctions.cxx`, `MathFunctions.h`, `mysqrt.cxx`, and `mysqrt.h` all look correct and I can't see anything that would cause an access violation error. The functions are well-contained and don't seem to be dealing with any potentially problematic memory operations such as dynamic memory allocation or array indexing, which are the usual suspects in cases of access violations.

### Expectation

I am expecting my application to run as expected when I test the executable created in the `build/Debug` or `build/Release` folder in CLion.

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Download the Official CMake Tutorial zip file [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Help/guide/tutorial).
2. Go to [Step5 - Exercise 1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Installing%20and%20Testing.html#step-5-installing-and-testing) as listed in this part of the official CMake tutorial (*Don't worry about the previous steps, they are each independent*)
3. Edit the `Step5/CMakeLists.txt` and `MathFunctions/CMakeLists.txt` as specified in Step5 - Exercise 1 (*Refer to the solutions given in the tutorial)
4. Run `cmake --install . --prefix "C:\Users\<YOUR USERNAME>\OneDrive\Desktop\Tutorial\" --config Debug`
5. Notice when trying to run the `Tutorial.exe` located in the bin folder of your new output directory on your Desktop, you get the runtime error. However, when running the executable normally (either by manually typing in the source files and using g++) the runtime error is not present in the executable.

## Approaches I have done to solve this error

- To better isolate the issue, I have created a new C++ project called "cmake-test-installable" that prints "Hello World" to the console. The project file structure is as follows...
  [image]
- Below is the code for each of the relevant files of the project...

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
     
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```c
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(cmake_test_installable)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(cmake_test_installable main.cpp)

# Create an installable target
install(TARGETS cmake_test_installable DESTINATION bin)
```

- Additionally, I am using the same toolchain (**MSYS2**) and generator (**Ninja**) as I did previously for the tutorial.
  [image]
- Also, the *version* of CMake I am using is **version 3.26.4**.
  [image]
- Likewise, it also successfully creates an executable similar to the tutorial project when I run the command `cmake --install`...

[image]

- However, when I attempt to run the executable that is now on my Desktop, I get the following error...
  [image]

Comment: `-1073741819` is `0xC0000005` which is access violation probably a bad pointer in the code.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: @Richard Critten, My apologies, I should I have specified more in my question. My code is running fine when I debug it. What is confusing me is the code itself doesn't particularly use pointers.

Comment: Are you talking about the example source code provided in the ZIP-file on the [CMake Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/) page?

Comment: @heap underrun Correct! That is exactly what I am working with currently. As specified in the tutorial, it is only necessary to edit the CMakeList.txt in the root of the project and in th e MathFunctions folder as I have done so.

Comment: Debug the release build and look at the stack frames when the debugger catches the access violation.

Comment: @RichardCritten So as suggested, I debugged the Tutorial program via CLion using a **RelWithDebInfo** build. Other than a peculiar stack frame switch where it switches to `new_allocator.h` the program runs fine. Could the call to `new_allocator.h` be the culprit? I am researching right now to see if that is the issue.

Comment: what's the output of `cmake --version`?

Comment: @starball The output is...
`cmake version 3.26.4`

Comment: Open a Windows command prompt. Go to the directory where your program is installed. Run it. Do you get the same error? There is nothing special based on your C++ code. My guess is that you have an environment runtime (shell) that is doing something strange.

Comment: @John Hanley So I did as you suggested. First, I opened a **Command Prompt (cmd)** and went to the directory on my desktop containing the executable HelloWorld.exe and attempted to run in the console. I got ***no*** output. Nothing. 
For additional testing, I did the exact same thing only this time using **PowerShell Preview**, and this time got the error as previously mentioned... `NativeCommandExitException: Program "HelloWorld.exe" ended with non-zero exit code: -1073741819.`

Comment: I interpret that to mean the EXE is corrupt. For Windows, I do not use MinGW so I don't have suggestions. Try building the EXE as a native Windows CLI program. Build with these commands from a Windows command prompt: 1) `cmake -S . -B build`. 2) `cmake --build build --config debug`. 3) Run the EXE in the build folder. It will probably be in a subfolder like debug on your system. If you get errors about no compiler, install the free Visual Studio Community 2022 edition.

Comment: Those steps might seem like extra work, but learning how to debug problems is also important.

Comment: @John Hanley You beautiful, glorious, bastard. We got working!!!  Using **Visual Studio** as the toolchain and **Visual Studio 17 2022** as the generator did it. Sincerely, thank you for helping. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck on your journey. CMake is pretty cool with everything it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to input from [@John Hanely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) I was able to deduce that issue was relying on **MinGW (MSYS2)** as the toolchain and **Ninja** as the generator. Why I don't exactly know specifically what causes this to work, changing my CMake profile to rely instead on **Visual Studio** as the toolchain and **Visual Studio 17 2022** as the generator actually correctly generates the installable executable.

[image]

Hope this helps all future people!